# Regex replace punctuation with whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a word counter function but it doesn't account for people using poor punctuation, for example:

`"hello.world"`

That would only count is as 1 word.

Instead it should count that as 2 words.

So instead I need a regex to replace comma's, full stops and any whitespace that is 1+ with a single whitespace.

Here's what I have so far:

```
proWords = proWords.replace(/[,\s]/, '\s');

negWords = negWords.replace(/[,\s]/, '\s');
```

Comment: As a side note, you can never be 100% sure that your word count is correct, just because languages are very complicated, humans are not always exact, etc.

Comment: @Leri Precisely why I needed to do something like this!

Comment: And how do you deal with other non-word chars, like `?!;` etc? I think whitelisting will work better here, `/\w+/g` or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replacement is just an ordinary string, it shouldn't contain regular expression escape sequences like `\s`.

```
proWords = proWords.replace(/[,.\s]+/g, ' ');
```

The `+` regular expression makes it replace any sequence of the characters, and you need the `g` modifier to replace multiple times.

Comment: The dot (.) matches any character, doesn't it?

Comment: @DanielS. Not inside `[]` it doesn't.

Comment: @DotKu Could you expand on that? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
proWords = proWords.replace(/[,\s]/, '\s');

negWords = negWords.replace(/[,\s]/, '\s');
```

to

```
proWords = proWords.replace(/[,\.\s]/, ' ');

negWords = negWords.replace(/[,\.\s]/, ' ');
```

This should work.